# Como calcular os segundos totais em uma lista de intervalo de datas ignorando interseções de intervalos em Python?

Tags: python, data

Estou tentando calcular o tempo total em uma lista de intervalos de datas em Python, sendo que se houver interseção entre os intervalos, deve se fundir para ser calculado como se fosse um novo intervalo.

**Intervalo 1:**

```
intervalos = [
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 10, 0, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 12, 0, 0)},
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 11, 0, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 13, 0, 0)},
]
self.assertEqual(calcular_tempo(intervalos), 10800)
```

**Intervalo 2:**

```
intervalos = [
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 10, 0, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 11, 0, 0)},
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 10, 30, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 11, 30, 0)},
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 12, 0, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 12, 30, 0)},
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 9, 0, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 13, 0, 0)},
]
self.assertEqual(calcular_tempo(intervalos), 14400)
```

**Intervalo 3:**

```
intervalos = [
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 10, 0, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 11, 0, 0)},
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 10, 30, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 11, 30, 0)},
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 12, 0, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 12, 30, 0)},
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 12, 40, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 12, 50, 0)},
  {'inicio': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 5, 0, 0), 'fim': datetime(2014, 11, 26, 10, 1, 0)},
]
self.assertEqual(calcular_tempo(intervalos), 25860)
```

Criei um método para realizar o cálculo, <strike>no entanto o resultado está falhando para alguns testes</strike> o código funciona mas a lógica está fraca.

**O método:**

```
def calcular_tempo(objetos):    
    intervalos = []
    intervalos_add = []
    intervalos_del = []

    for objeto in objetos:
        if intervalos:
            for intervalo in intervalos:
                if intervalo['inicio'] < objeto['inicio'] < intervalo['fim']:
                    if objeto['fim'] > intervalo['fim']:
                       intervalos_del.append(intervalo)
                       intervalos_add.append({'inicio': intervalo['inicio'], 'fim': objeto['fim']})

                elif intervalo['fim'] > objeto['fim'] > intervalo['inicio']:
                    if objeto['inicio'] < intervalo['inicio']:
                        intervalos_del.append(intervalo)
                        intervalos_add.append({'inicio': objeto['inicio'], 'fim': intervalo['fim']})

                elif objeto['inicio'] < intervalo['inicio'] and objeto['fim'] > intervalo['fim']:
                    intervalos_del.append(intervalo)
                    intervalos_add.append(objeto)

                elif objeto['inicio'] != intervalo['inicio'] and objeto['fim'] != intervalo['fim']:
                    intervalos_add.append(objeto)
                else:
                    intervalos.append(objeto)

                for deletar in intervalos_del:
                    intervalos.remove(deletar)

                intervalos_sem_repeticoes = []
                for add in intervalos_add:
                    if add not in intervalos_sem_repeticoes:
                        intervalos_sem_repeticoes.append(add)

                intervalos = intervalos + intervalos_sem_repeticoes
                intervalos_add = []
                intervalos_del = []

            segundos_totais = 0

            for intervalo in intervalos:
                segundos_totais += (intervalo['fim'] - intervalo['inicio']).total_seconds()

            return segundos_totais
```

Creio que eu esteja redundante na lógica e deixando a desejar na verificação dos intervalos. Eu não ia colocar o método que fiz para não influenciar, seria interessante se fizessem essa lógica do zero, pois deve ser mais simples do que o algoritmo que fiz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minha sugestão é a seguinte:

1. Ordene os intervalos pela data de início;
2. Para cada intervalo, se seu início for menor que o fim do último, mescle os dois:

Exemplo (passou nos seus 3 testes):

```
def calcular_tempo(intervalos):
    intervalos = sorted(intervalos, key=lambda x: x['inicio'])
    ultimo = intervalos[0]
    for i in intervalos[1:]:
        if i['inicio'] < ultimo['fim']:
            ultimo['fim'] = max(ultimo['fim'], i['fim']) # Mescla os dois intervalos
            i['fim'] = i['inicio'] # Zera um deles
        else:
            ultimo = i
    return sum((i['fim'] - i['inicio']).total_seconds() for i in intervalos)
```

P.S. Esse exemplo de código **modifica os intervalos originais** - se precisa deles depois da chamada do método, sugiro ou cloná-los ou alterar o código acima de acordo.

Comment: Acabo de descobrir que o meu código estava funcionando, me enganei em um dos testes. No entanto esse seu código funcionou perfeitamente, o que chega ser irritante pelo tempo que você levou para fazer isso, kkk.